# Won't boot into recovery or normal after running chmod command as root in recovery

Tags: boot, chmod

I screwed up big time with my home server. I lost sudo on my user account and was following a guide to re-enable it. I went into recovery mode and when into the root shell and ran these commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chown root:root /usr/bin/
chmod -R 4755 /usr/bin/
```

Expect I did read the guide correctly and did a -R to the whole bin dir. Now when I start linux i get a bunch of errors and even if I start it in recovery mode it still show a bunch of errors and I end up in a bash terminal where I cant seem to do anything.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using a live install of Ubuntu and using the terminal to restore permissions on the `/usr/bin` directory. The only issue is that I had to run `chmod -R 775 /usr/bin` which means some of files that had sticky bits are now broken. I did run `chmod 4775 /usr/bin/sudo` which should solve that file. However, not sure what other files need sticky bits and have heard that it is a security risk to have everything in the bin folder be `775`.

So maybe I will just end up doing a fresh install. On the upside everything seems to working and have not noticed any issues.